# How to make a countdown timer in Java?

Tags: java, swing, bluej

I need a countdown timer that does a task every second (change a label's text so it appears to be counting down). I've looked at a lot of the Java docs and also at examples online but I don't really understand any of them (I'm new to programming) so If you could explain in simple terms that would be great!

I've started off by making a `Timer timer;` and then `timer = new Timer()` when I want it to start, now I'm stuck :(

Comment: I would not recommend using graphical programming systems like BlueJ, I find it nearly impossible to learn from. Use an IDE like Eclipse.

Comment: I heard Eclipse is a lot better, unfortunately I'm a student and the university says we must use BlueJ.

Comment: Your university is very poor if they say that you absolutely have to use BlueJ... it is not even a real IDE. Where are you going to school?

Comment: Our university made bluej, that's why - University of Kent -.- I'm only in my first year, I think next year we move onto Eclipse, thank god, I hate BlueJ!

Comment: //static int i = 0;
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("0");
        
        frame.add(label);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        Timer timer = null;
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText(++i+" ");
            }
        };
        
        timer = new Timer(1000, listener);
        timer.start();

Comment: That should be in an answer, not a comment.